# jquery - perform effect on any event

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 5 elements in a page.
i have selected them using class names  `$('.class')`

i am trying to perform a function for those selected elements irrespective of event (click or hover or watever).

eg:

```
$('.class').hover(function(){definition1});  
$('.class').click(function(){definition1});
```

i dont want to have 2 seperate event as above 2, instead i want the function to be executed irrespective of whether its hover or click event.

Comment: What can you possibly want to do on every possible event besides log events?  Do you really want to run javascript on every single mousemove event?  I'd suggest you share what you're really trying to accomplish so we can perhaps provide a more suitable answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.class').bind('click mouseenter', function() {
    // Go nuts.
});
```

<sup>(if using jQuery >= 1.7, swap `bind()` with `on()`.)</sup>

Keep in mind that `hover()`'s second argument is for `mouseleave` event, which you haven't written anything for here.

If you want to cover most events, pass in 'blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click dblclick mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave change select submit keydown keypress keyup error' as the first argument.

You could also try to detect them with code by iterating over properties that start with `on`, but it sounds too flaky to me.

Comment: Thank you Alex, hover, i mentioned just for a sample. But is there a way to do all events instead of mentioning it one by one. like .ready() for document?

Comment: @KannanLg—it is very unusual to want to attach a listener for *every* event. Most elements have at least 10 intrinsic events (click, dblclick, mousedown, mouseup, and so on), there are many others as well. If you want a listener for each event, you will have to list them by name.

Answer (score 2):

To **bind multiple events** to one element in jQuery 1.7 and later you can do the following by separating event names by spaces:

```
jQuery('.class').on('click hover mousenter mouseleave', function(event){
    // do what you need to do
});
```

which you can see in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DcAJP/1/).

But: **be careful, because you can easily fire the event too much times** (more than necessary and more than enough). By binding so many events some may be called unnecessarily (as in the example above the code will be fired twice when the mouse cursor will leave the element it hovered over).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to exec a function without any event put it in

```
$(function(){
    function test(){definition1}
});
```

then in html

```
<body onload="test();">
```

Comment: yes. I would say I wanted a similar one. One thing missing here is, I wanted to select the elements and perform an action without any event. 
so, something like... $('.class').function(){}

Comment: my bad mis-understood the question

Comment: I guess you can still select the needed 5 elements in the function itself. It would be more clear if you can let us know the elements you want to select

Comment: i wanted to select $('.portlet') (element selection by class)
and perform function(){....}

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".portlet").**ANYEVENT**(function(){
    $("p").slideToggle();
  });
});

Comment: May be you can try something $(.class).each(function(index){....}). Not tried this though